# How to convert SREC motorola format (.s19) file to hex file?

Tags: assembly, hex, motorola

I tried online softwares and found hex to .s19 file converter but not vice versa. Are those softwares available? otherwise what is the procedure to convert .s19 to hex file manually?

Comment: Try `objcopy` from the GNU binutils.

Comment: @fuz thank you for your reply. Mine is windows 64 bit. Iam not able to get GNU binutils for my system. Can you briefly tell what are  the steps to follow?.

Comment: Yes, you can get them.  Check out MinGW which should contain a copy.  Note that Stack Overflow is not for software recommendations, so your question is going to get closed soon.

Comment: oh i see,iam new here. Anyhow iam able to convert .s19 to hex manually.

Comment: they are easy to parse and generate, 15 minutes to half an hour to write a tool if you cant find an existing one or get it working.

Comment: From a deleted answer: `srec_cat input file.s19 -o outputfile.hex -Intel` using "SREC tool, which is a free to download".  Another recent answer linked to it, http://srecord.sourceforge.net/, in case that mostly-link answer gets deleted.  (Which isn't the answer's fault; a question like this unavoidably invites such answers.)

Answer (score 3):

There is an open source software solution called “SRecord”. It is available from the following website: http://srecord.sourceforge.net/. This software solution includes a versatile program called “srec_cat”, which make it quick and easy to convert between files in the HEX and SREC format. The “srec_cat” program works on both Windows and Linux.

here is the website that can  help you: https://www.feaser.com/en/blog/2017/11/conversions-between-hex-and-srec-files/

Comment: this command can convert .s19 and even .mot format as well, I think it checks the content of the file  if it is in srecord  of Motorola  format then it will convert it into intel hex

Comment: srec_cat yourFileinsrecordformat.mot -Motorola -o yourConvertedIntelhexfile.hex -Intel

Answer (score 0):

In the hope that it is useful:
I stumbled over an SOB-file (.sob file extension), which really is a Motorola-S-record format:

As user @fuz mentioned, the Linux tool `objcopy` can be used for conversion:

```
# convert SREC file to binary:
objcopy -I srec -O binary a.sob a.bin

# convert SREC to Intel-HEX:
objcopy -I srec -O ihex  a.sob a.hex
```